# MySQL using LIKE command to find between semi-colon

Tags: php, mysql

This is my data

```
385_white   99  swarovski   12  black;blue
386_white   99  swarovski   12  black;blue;green
387_white   99  swarovski   12  yellow;green
389_white   99  swarovski   12  white;silver
385_white   99  swarovski   12  silver
```

This is an example query

```
SELECT *  FROM `products` WHERE `category` LIKE 'swarovski' AND `colours` LIKE 'silver'
```

The results returned are empty. If the user was to have black, then it should return both the first records. There is no way for me to edit the `color;color;color` format. That is fee sable at this time.

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE colours LIKE '%silver%'?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The penalty of a denormalized schema like this is you have to do more work with your query to ensure an accurate match:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `products` 
WHERE `category` = 'swarovski' 
AND (
    `colours` = 'silver' 
    OR `colours` LIKE 'silver;%' 
    OR `colours` LIKE '%;silver;%' 
    OR `colours` LIKE '%;silver' 

)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58f66/1)

Comment: Will this prevent someone from typing "silverish"

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Yes, it will.

Comment: I think regex is better than 3 LIKES and 1 equation

Answer (score 2):

I prefer doing a single comparison:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `products` 
WHERE `category` = 'swarovski' and
      concat(';', `colours`, ';') like ';silver;'
```

That is, add the delimiters to the beginning and end of the column and then do a single `like`.